# AFNetworking - Upload video along with other parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afhttpclient, afhttprequestoperation

I want to upload video to web service along with some other parameters. I want to upload **userID**, **videoID** and **video** to web service. While uploading, all the parameters other than video is being sent to web service. I've checked at web service end, and the video is not coming with the request. I am using the following code.

```
- (void)uploadVideoAtLocalPath:(NSString *)videoPath videoID:(NSString *)videoID userID:(NSString *)userID {

    NSString *strServerURL = @"www.mysite.com/user/uploadVideo";
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:strServerURL];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:URL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

        // userID
        NSData *userIDData = [userID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:userIDData name:@"userID"];

        // videoID
        NSData *videoIDData = [videoID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:videoIDData name:@"videoID"];

        // video
        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"video" fileName:@"video.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
    }];

    [request setURL:URL];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [AFHTTPRequestOperation addAcceptableStatusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(100, 500)]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response String: %@", operation.responseString);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
    }];

    [client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Could anyone let me know whether I am doing it correct? If not, could anyone please tell me how to upload video to web service along with other parameters?

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Have you checked if `videoData` is nil?

Comment: Can you try to enclose the userID and videoID into NSDictionary and put it inside the parameters in the method multipartFormRequestWithMethod instead of putting nil?

Comment: @AttilaH: Hi, videoData is not nil. I've checked it. Thanks.

Comment: @verbumdei, Hi, I've tried that too but no use. Anyway I will try again (may be I have not done it right previously), and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: thanks @EmptyStack, by using your code I was able to upload image to my server.

Comment: @Praveen, Sorry. Not yet tried it. Will try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have got success from this method. You can also try.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well in this method. I had the same issue. But, i have fixed it like mixing of *POST* & *GET* methods. I just sent my parameters as *GET* method like below -

> NSString *strServerURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.mysite.com/user/uploadVideo&userID=%d&videoID=%d", 1, 55];

and, sent my video data in *POST* method as per your method -

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

    // video
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"video" fileName:@"video.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
}];
```

You better try to modify your webservice and try like above way. It should works.

Cheers!